# Webi: On opening, filter data by current user name which can be in or not in a given list (no prompt)

Tags: filter, webi

(*SAP BusinessObjects BI Platform 4.3 Support Pack 1 Patch 11 Version : 14.3.1.4142.11*)

*Disclosure: I'm not born english speaking, but if I have understood correctly, we should now use "they", instead of he/she, etc. That is what I did here. Just to be sure no one is confused while reading.*

Hi everyone, it's me again for a webi question.

I have this report in which I have data for a group of workers. These data are: their name, when they work, where, which activity they do, etc.

| Worker name | Other information |
| --- | --- |
| Worker A | ... |
| Worker B | ... |
| ... | ... |
| Worker M | ... |

Worker Z for example is not in the list.

I currently have a filter "name" (multi-list), which allows us to select one or more workers (Worker A, Worker B,...). By default, it shows all data.

There is an auto-refresh on opening.

The function CurrentUser() returns the worker ID, not the name.

| Worker name | Worker ID |
| --- | --- |
| Worker A | 238x01f93 |
| Worker B | 4j192h60a |
| ... | ... |
| Worker Z | 09ad812jn |

I have two kind of user, that can see this report:

1. A user whose name is present in the list of workers (e.g. Worker A).
2. A user whose name is not present in the list of workers (e.g. Worker Z).

**My goal:**

1. When the user opens the report, the filter "name" is set by default with their name (e.g. Worker A). This way, they see only their data. If they want to see the data of other workers, they can easily change the filter to select other workers (e.g. Worker B and C). It should not be limited.
2. When the user (Worker Z) opens the report, they see all data. They can naturally use the filter to select only one or a few workers if they want to.

**What I did/tried:**

I can change things in the view (database), in the universe or/and in the report. I only tried things on the report level, because I could not see any ways to help me solve this on universe or view level. (But I am open to suggestions! :-) )

Create a variable to:

- Filter for only current user ID. It worked, but only if the user name was in the list. Another problem is that the workers don't know this user ID and can't work with it.

```
=CurrentUser()
```

- Search in the list, if the current user ID exists. Does not work. It shows always all data.

```
If (Pos([Personalnumber];CurrentUser()) > 0) Then CurrentUser() Else [Personalnumber]
```

- Link the current worker ID with their name if they are in the list. It worked well for them, but I could not find a way to have all workers, if the current user name is not in the list.

```
If (CurrentUser() = [Personalnumber]) Then [Name] Else "All"
```

I read so many posts, but none for my case. It is often to prevent user to see all the data, which is not what I want. They should be able to see everything, if they want to.

We only want to filter for the current user for performance means and also efficiency. The user does not have to select themselves the right filter and loose time. Most of the time, they only wants to see their data.

Can anyone help me?

Don't hesitate to tell me if something is unclear or missing. :-)

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Hi everyone,
It has been a bit more than a month. Can really no one help me with this problem? I am willing to improve my question if it is not clear enough or lack information!

Comment: Hi everyone, I'm still looking for a solution to this problem. :-)